# What's the difference between overloading operator new and operator new[] in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The `operator new` and `operator new[]` has the same function prototype: `void * (size_t size)`. What should I pay attention to when I'm going to overload them?

Is that OK if I only overload `operator new`?

And what's the difference between overload `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`?

Comment: One if for single objects, one is for arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator new` is used for creating single object, such as:

```
my_class* p = new my_class;
```

`operator new[]` is used for creating object's array, such as:

```
my_class* p = new my_class[10];
```

> Is that OK if I only overload operator new?

It depends on if you need special treatment for array version (`operator new[]`). By default `operator new[]` will call `operator new`.

Basically, if you need to overload `operator new`, it's better to overload `operator new[]` too, because if you want to implement your own memory management, it's a good idea to keep them all consistent. And don't forget the nothrow and placement version(as member functions only, the global version can't be displaced).

The same is true for `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`.

Comment: `operator new[]` already calls `operator new` by default. The nothrow versions already call the corresponding throwing versions by default. And the placement form (`void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;` and friends) cannot be replaced at all.

Comment: @T.C. So the answer to "Is that OK if I only overload operator new?" should be yes?

Comment: operator new calls constructor but does the array version also call the constructor?

Comment: @jayatubi `operator new` doesn't call the ctor, the new expression (i.e. `new my_class`) does. It's true for array version too, `new my_class[10]` will call the ctor on every element.

Comment: @T.C. Is it implemention dependent? I tried with [clang](http://rextester.com/HBYJ6246), it doesn't call `operator new`, while [gcc](http://rextester.com/NKAL19293) and [vc](http://rextester.com/LHM55337) do.

Comment: @songyuanyao No, just clang being more aggressive in optimizing allocations. Try making `p2` `volatile`.

Comment: @T.C. I tried but nothing changed. http://rextester.com/YEHL61185 Does the standard mention it? I think optimization shouldn't change the behaviour, if the standard describe it explicitly.

Comment: @songyuanyao Make the pointer volatile, not the pointee - `int* volatile p2`. This is a special case; [N3664](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3664.html) grants explicit permission for this optimization.

Comment: so these operators just act as the same as what malloc/free does?

Comment: @jayatubi malloc/free won't call constructors/destructors.

Comment: @T.C. So clang just omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function here? I got it. Thanks. But in this case that means the user defined `operator new` will not be called probably for the array allocation.

Comment: @jayatubi They all allocate memory, in this point of view, yes. Basically new expression do 2 things: call `operator new` to allocate memery, and then call ctor to initialize(for class only).

Answer (score 0):

new creates an instance, whereas new[] creates a an array.

new[] will almost have little memory overhead compared to new to store the size of the array.

You can't use non-default constructors with new[].

new must be used with delete.

new[] must be used with delete[].

another Difference:

new[] is an operator to allocate and initialize an array of objects and return a pointer to the first element.

This differs from the new operator which has the same behavior but for one allocation, not an array